# Mobile/Deployable Space Elevator?

Tags: science-based, space-travel, space-constructs

Would it be possible to have a space elevator that could be coiled up stored in a ship during transport and then deployed from orbit down to a planet upon arrival?

Additionally,

- About how much space would said coiled up elevator cable fit into?
- What would be some of the difficulties encountered in deploying the elevator?
- Could said elevator be undeployed; detached from the planetary surface and reeled back up, what would be some of the difficulties involved in doing this?
- Finally, what would be necessary to secure the elevator to the surface? Could only certain sites be used?

Comment: Exactly as much as the plot requires. No material in current human tech can make it even 1% of the distance necessary before snapping under its own weight, so it really just depends on the properties of the handwavium of which the cable is made.

Comment: Okay, except I would like an answer based in some actual science. And that doesn't answer the other questions like what problems might arise in getting it down to the surface and keeping it there, etc. . . (also carbon nanotubes are a good be)

Comment: one question per post, please, and with enough details to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. It depends on how many sci-fi like elements you want to apply. Right now, there are huge issues in the production of carbon nano-tubes long enough and in large enough amounts to support the construction of a space elevator. Going through such an undertaking however would suggest you already have easy access to space as you are performing extra work to move the entire space elevator up into space before lowering it again (you're moving it up, just to move it down later).

You biggest issues will be anchoring the elevator to the surface of the planet. You're going to need to anchor it to the surface, because you need a counterweight to keep the cable up in the air. Basically gravity pulls the cable down, and the counter weight pulls the cable up with centrifugal force as it spins around the earth. If the space elevator is not attached, then it will simply float away or fall to the earth as you are removing one of these factors. It's far safer to attach it to the ground and have some extra centrifugal force as slight variations in wind speed will be more than enough to tip a perfect, floating/detached space elevator situation.

Of course, choosing an attachment point is going to be extremely hard. Not only will you need a very solid foundation in place, since you are lowering the cable, you're going to have issues directing it. You can try it yourself. Get a long string, put a coin on the ground. Now stand on top of a skyscraper and hit the coin with your string. Of course, you have the magic of handwavium, so it's not impossible for you to attach an anchor like device to the end of your space elevator which will help pull the space elevator down.

In terms of the size of the elevator. That would be completely up to you. Factors like the planet size, weather conditions, amount of goods you are moving up and down. Speed of movement, redundancy in design all factor in.

Comment: "In terms of the size of the elevator. That would be completely up to you." Excuse me, I don't think so. Not unless you want throw out any sense of physical reality, then you have a 'magic' space elevator. A space elevator would be around 144,000 kilometres in length. Apart from your last paragraph, your answer is a good, helpful discussion of space elevators.

Comment: @a4android Do you want your space elevator to lift 1KG at a time? or 1 Ton? 1000 Tons? How much weight does it lift will dictate a large portion of the size. Sure the height of the space elevator is pretty much fixed, but the diameter and amount of concurrent cabling would be dependent on the load you expect to manage. You also have the speed of the elevator. Expected wind speed, redundant cables for safety. Height is not the only factor you need to consider. Everything else will multiply off it.

Comment: Height is an important measure and as you rightly point out everything flows from it. The *real* problem is the carrying capacity of the spaceship lowering it. Most space elevators would be much, much bigger than the vessel.

Answer (score 3):

A [**skyhook**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure)) may be a better answer than a space elevator.

A skyhook is a cable suspended from a large space station (or, in this case, spaceship) that does not reach all the way down to the planet's surface. The cable rotates around the spaceship, and with the right combination of orbital speed and cable rotation, its end could have zero velocity compared to the planet's surface when it is lowest. Planes could then attach or detach payloads. Attached payloads would be flung into space with the rotation of the cable.

A rotating skyhook would require adding rotation to the cable as it is unreeled and later slowing rotation as it is reeled back in. These maneuvers would require a lot of energy. An alternative would be a non-rotating skyhook lowered from geostationary orbit, but the cable would have to be far longer than for a rotating skyhook in low orbit.

It might be possible to shoot the cable out backwards in the orbit. As the heavy end point of the hook moves at lower orbital speed, it will drop into lower orbit and eventually gain a pendulum motion, which might have to be accelerated by moving the spaceship out when the cable is at its lowest, and then back down when the cable is highest, until the right pendulum speed is gained - like making a yo-yo swing faster. At the upper parts of the pendulum swing, when the hook moves very slowly, it would not require a lot of energy to move payloads in or out the cable. The weakness of this approach is that on every second swing, the cable would pass through the atmosphere at very high speed; basically double the orbital speed; with associated friction problems.

Comment: I think the skyhook idea is more feasible but I don’t think it can be reeled in for same problems I discuss in my elevator answer. But a ship with a fixed rotating hook I think could settle into high orbit and slowly, over many orbits, lower itself such that the hook enters the atmosphere, with stabilizing engines along the hook’s length to prevent bending.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword here is mobile. You see, a Space Elevator is nothing more than a really tall satellite: the sheer weight and centripetal force on the far ends keep the thing pointing upwards and downwards, it doesn't even need to be tethered to the ground with the correct weight balance and orbital speed, it will just float with it's mass pulling towards the planet and it's inertia pulling outwards. How would it work? With a really dense counterweight that your ship could reel out closer or further, to adjust to the weight of the space elevator reeling down from your ship to the planet. If I understood the concept correctly, the center of mass would need to be geostationary, any part of the space elevator structure closer than that point would be pulled into the planet, and any part of the structure further away from the planet from that point would be pulled away from the planet. Your center of mass is too low? Reel out the counterweight. Too high? Reel in the counterweight. Etc.

The ship in the middle would work as a station (as in space  and as in trains), and if the thing needs to be moved to another planet, you just need to reel in both the counterweight and the space elevator cable at the right speeds so that both masses moving would cancel each other's inertia and when you finish, take the ship and move it to geostationary orbit of another planet or moon. It's dead simple, as long as you park it over the planet's equator. That makes for a fairly limited but usefull contraption if you have material strength big enough (or a gravity low enough for current material strenghts... you totally could build a Space Elevator on the Moon with stainless steel: far lower gravity). Really the only handwaving needed here it's the tensile strenght of the cables goind "down" or "up" from the main ship.

You don't want the thing parked over the equator, or the place where you want the cargo to be picked up is far away from the equator? Well, that's where things get insteresting... you will need far bigger material strengths, and you may as well think of not one, but several cables going down into the planet (and this time, you will need the thing tethered into the ground). This cables would work as a seafaring ship's anchors, and by adjusting the length you reel out or in of each of this, you could make the ship slide "north or south" of the equator. At a higher cost in strength needed, because now the elevator cable would have lateral forces when the elevator climbs up or down (the ground wouldn't be "down", but at an angle).

[image: A space elevator tethered to NY and Santiago de Chile]
Here, take this image as a reference. This space elevator would be tethered to both New York city and Santiago de Chile. If you reel in the anchor goind down to NY and release some cable on the one tethered to SC, you would make the thing to stay in a more northern position, over Mexico.

Or you can go the easier way by keeping the ship over the equator and playing with the position of the tether anchors. You can place your first one where you want by adjusting where's the second (you want the tether to be in Washington DC? anchor the other one closer to the north and the ship/station would stay at the same place).

Sorry, my english is trash. You can find this kind of concepts in the youtube channel "science and futurism with isaac arthur", he has several videos on the concept of space elevators or space hooks. I would recomend this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc8_AuzeYKE

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: not likely given what we know of chemistry today.

We don’t have a material that can do a space elevator today. But research is in progress. One of the barriers is that as we go up the list of stronger materials, we find they also decrease in flexibility. There’s some hopeful open research in material science, particularly around carbon, but the working hypothesis (last time I talked to researchers in the field, 2 years ago) is that any material strong enough won’t be flexible at all.

You might suggest segmenting the cable with hinges so it can roll up, but hinges are weak points, and they apply strain to the material, which would, if the hypothesis is true, break it.

The skyhook idea proposed by someone else seems more likely... not easy, but I think the elevator option is right out, unless you just handwave the problem.